# ARM NEON convert f32 to s32 with round toward even

Tags: arm, neon, bankers-rounding

Is there any functions that controls rounding mode of vcvt_s32_f32 intrinsic? I want to use round toward even instead of round toward negative infinity.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get that "round to even" Could you give an example what it is supposed to do? Maybe then I could write a bit hacking routine doing that for you.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Still, I don't know how to handle 1.0 and -1.0 for example. The simple bit hacking algorithm of mine will turn them to 2 and 0 each. Is it ok?

Comment: I mean that 2.5 must be 2, 3.5 must be 4 and so on.

Comment: but what about 1 and -1? they aren't even. That's what I was asking about.

Comment: Hmm, unless of course, given the "bankers' rounding" tag, we're actually talking "Round to nearest, _ties_ to even". In that case, that's what NEON already does! (the "negative infinity" stated in the question is incorrect)

Comment: Neon simply truncates floating part, but I want 2 for 2.5, 4 for 3.5, 2 for 2.4, 3 for 2.6, etc

Comment: Ah, on closer inspection it's the VCVT instruction's "always round towards zero" behaviour rather than NEON specifically. Still, I think everything here still applies.

Comment: What he probably means is round towards nearest, ties to even, the default IEEE-754 rounding mode. This is given by (before armv8) VCVTR instruction. The caveat here is that the rounding mode is selectable, so if your caller has changed the global default rounding mode, you'll round unexpectedly. Armv8 and later and you want vcvtns.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't change the rounding mode.

NEON is designed for performance rather than precision, and thus is restricted compared to VFP. Unlike VFP, it's not a full IEEE 754 implementation, and is hardwired to certain settings - quoting from the ARM ARM:

> - denormalized numbers are flushed to zero
> - only default NaNs are supported
> - the Round to Nearest<sup>*</sup> rounding mode selected
> - untrapped exception handling selected for all floating-point exceptions

The specific case of floating-point to integer conversion is slightly different in that the behaviour of the `VCVT` instruction in this case (for both VFP and NEON) is to ignore the selected rounding mode and always round towards zero. The `VCVTR` instruction which does use the selected rounding mode is only available in VFP.

The ARMv8 architecture introduced a whole bunch of rounding and conversion instructions
for using specific rounding modes, but I suspect that's not much help in this particular case. If you want to do conversions under a different rounding mode on ARMv7 and earlier, you'll either have to use VFP (if available) or some bit-hacking to implement it manually.

<sub>* The ARM ARM uses IEEE 754-1985 terminology, so more precisely this is round to nearest, ties to even</sub>